# Solve the following equation $\sqrt[5]{x^3-6x^2+9x}=\sqrt[3]{x^5+6x^2-9x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the following equation in $\mathbb R$
>   $$\sqrt[5]{x^3-6x^2+9x}=\sqrt[3]{x^5+6x^2-9x}$$

It seems that we need to use here some substitution, but I don't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $u = \sqrt[5]{x^3-6x^2+9x}$ and $v=\sqrt[3]{x^5+6x^2-9x}\,$, then $u=v$ and $u^5+v^3=x^3+x^5\,$.

It follows that $u=x$ is a solution, which gives:

$$
\sqrt[5]{x^3-6x^2+9x} = x \iff x(x-3)^2 = x^5 \iff x = 0 \;\;\lor\;\;x^4 - (x-3)^2=0
$$

Still left to show that $u=x$ gives *all* the real solutions.

Comment: $x=u$ because $f(x)=x^3+x^5$ is increasing?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Right. I was overcomplicating the injectivity part.